# window.reload reloads before fetching response

Tags: cakephp, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

i am using jqueryMobile with backbonejs.
task: login form with email and password fields. Fill the form and redirect to same form with 3 links:

- update profile
- change pwd
- logout

Problem: when logout is clicked i wish to redirect it back to the login form(same page) with message-"successfully logged out."

what i did:
in view.js:

```
$('#logoutClick').click(function() {
        console.log("hi");
        this.collection = new Fan();
        this.collection.logoutFan();
        window.location.reload(true);
    });
```

in myController(of cakephp):

```
public function mobile_logout() {
    $status = true;
    $event = array();
    $data = array();

    $this->Auth->logout();
    $this->Session->setFlash('Successfully Logged out', 'flash_failure');
    $this->Session->delete('Auth.Fan');

    $this->set('status',$status);
    $this->set('output',$data);
    $this->render('/Layouts/json/mobile',false);
}
```

now when i click on logout, the page is redirected but the message is not rendered.(i guess the page reloads before fetching the response).
When i inspect element in chrome-I can see logout.json with no available preview(json response from controller isn't there).
How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do reload. Use redirect:
window.location = 'yourloginpage?msg=success';

Answer (score 0):

As jQuery mobile simulates one big web page, you cannot reffer to another pages. Using:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Opens a new view, where jQM starts working once again (it downloads all header files etc). It works like links with rel="external"

If you want to keep jQM working in such case you have to add all headers to your html files and you should be aware you cannot reffer to previous page because it is deleted from DOM.

I did it some different way. It is not perfect:) Try to redirect to another page using `$.mobile.changePage("./newpage.html)`. In this new page add event `pageinit` and redirect back to the start page.